# Linear forms on the algebra of functions

Tags: measure-theory, information-geometry

In the book "Information Geometry", Nihat Ay et al. consider the following scenario in Chapter $2.1$ on page $24$:

> We consider a non-empty and finite set $I$. The real algebra of functions $I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is denoted by $\mathcal F(I)$, and its unity $\mathbb 1_{I}$ or simply $\mathbb 1$ is given by $\mathbb 1(i) = 1$, $i\in I$. [...] We naturally interpret linear forms $\sigma:\ \mathcal F(I) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ as signed measures on $I$ and denote the corresponding dual space $\mathcal F(I)^{\star}$ [...].

My problem is understanding how linear forms $\sigma$  can be interpreted as signed measures on $I$? After all, $\mathcal F(I)$ is not a sigma-algebra, since it is not even a subset of the power set $\mathcal P(I)$?

Answer (score 0):

I see how you got confused here, since $\sigma : \mathcal{F}(I) \to \mathbb{R}$ *looks* like it might itself describe a measure. After all, some people use $\mathcal{F}$ as notation for a $\sigma$-algebra, and signed measures should be functions from a $\sigma$-algebra to $\mathbb{R}$. The authors should probably have been more careful, since this is not at all what's meant!

Instead, $\mathcal{F}(I)$ should be thought of as continuous functions $I \to \mathbb{R}$, where $I$ is given the discrete topology. In this sense, maybe a better name for $\mathcal{F}(I)$ would be $C(I,\mathbb{R})$. Of course, the (measure theoretic) [Riesz Representation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem) tells us that

> For every linear functional $\varphi : C(I,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}$, there is a unique (signed, radon) measure $\mu_\varphi$ on $I$ so that $\varphi(f) = \int_I f \ d\mu_\varphi$

This $\mu_\varphi$ is slightly tricky to define in general, but since $I$ is a discrete space it's really not hard at all!
Here $\mu_\varphi(E)$ is defined to be $\varphi( \chi_E )$, where $\chi_E : C(I, \mathbb{R})$ is the characteristic function of $E \subseteq I$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that (almost) clarifies my confusion! ;-) could you please explain, though, why we can use the Riesz Representation Theorem here? i) The authors did not assume that $\mathcal F(I) = C(I, \mathbb R)$, i.e. we could have functions that are not continuous? ii) According to the Wikipedia link, $I$ needs to be a locally compact Hausdorff space, yet the authors did not assume this, they only assumed that $I$ is non-empty and finite.

Comment: @Hermi -- In the case $I$ is nonempty and finite, then (equipped with the discrete topology) it is compact, hausdorff, and _every_ function $I \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. For proofs, see almost any first (point set) topology textbook. Better, these all make great exercises ;)